# InvalidUseOfMatchersException when using Matchers.eq() with other mocked values

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

In my JUnit class  i have the below code:

```
@Mock
private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

@Mock
WidgetHelper widgetHelper;

@Mock
JSONObject jsonObject;

@Mock
Date date;

verify(widgetHelper, times(1)).invokeAuditService(servletRequest, date, anyString(), 
                        Matchers.eq("Member_Servicing_Email_Update"), jsonObject, anyString());
```

I'm getting the below output:

```java
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
//incorrect:
someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
//correct:
someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

The thing I want to achieve is: I want to test if the 4th argument to the method contains the string `"Member_Servicing_Email_Update"` or not. Rest of the arguments can be mocked. I used `Matchers.anyObject()` for others and I got error saying `cannot match anyObject to java.lang.String, Date, HttpServlet` and so on. What needs to be done here? I also just put `eq("Member_Servicing_Email_Update")` but `eq` was not recognized.

Comment: You need to use either matchers or concrete values for all parameters. You can't mix them like you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Matchers.eq` for all raw parameters:

```
verify(widgetHelper, times(1)).invokeAuditService(Matchers.eq(servletRequest), Matchers.eq(date), anyString(), 
                Matchers.eq("Member_Servicing_Email_Update"), Matchers.eq(jsonObject), anyString());
```

> When using matchers, **all arguments have to be provided by matchers**

Comment: PowerMockito.doNothing().when(widgetHelper).invokeAuditService(Matchers.eq(servletRequest), Matchers.eq(date), anyString(), 
                Matchers.eq("Member_Servicing_Email_Update"), Matchers.eq(jsonObject), anyString());
  
  verify(widgetHelper, times(1)).invokeAuditService(Matchers.eq(servletRequest), Matchers.eq(date), anyString(), 
                Matchers.eq("Member_Servicing_Email_Update1"), Matchers.eq(jsonObject), anyString());
This code is giving me unfinished stubbing exception. here invokeAuditService method is void

Comment: @Coder17 can you ask a new question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59643836/unfinishedstubbingexception-when-working-with-donothing-method-for-void-methods