# UnfinishedStubbingException when working with doNothing method for void methods

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

The below code is causing   UnfinishedStubbingException

```
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(widgetHelper).invokeAuditService(Matchers.eq(servletRequest), Matchers.eq(date), anyString(), Matchers.eq("Member_Servicing_Email_Update"), Matchers.eq(jsonObject), anyString());

     verify(widgetHelper, times(1)).invokeAuditService(Matchers.eq(servletRequest), Matchers.eq(date), anyString(), Matchers.eq("Member_Servicing_Email_Update1"), Matchers.eq(jsonObject), anyString());


org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
    -> at ....

    E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
    Examples of correct stubbing:
        when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
        when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
        doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
    Hints:
     1. missing thenReturn()
     2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
```

what I'm I missing here?
Below is the method signature of invokeAuditService

```
public static void invokeAuditService(HttpServletRequest request, Date serviceCallTime, String response, 
            String activityKey, JSONObject detailsReplaceVal, String pmAccountId){
        AuditLogUtils.invokeAuditService(request, date, response, activityKey, json,  someString);
    }
```

I did this:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(WidgetHelper.class);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(WidgetHelper.class);
        WidgetHelper.invokeAuditService(Matchers.eq(servletRequest), Matchers.eq(date), anyString(), 
                Matchers.eq("Member_Servicing_Email_Update"), Matchers.eq(jsonObject), anyString());

verify(widgetHelper, times(1)).invokeAuditService(Matchers.eq(servletRequest), Matchers.eq(date), anyString(), 
                Matchers.eq("Member_Servicing_Email_Update123"), Matchers.eq(jsonObject), anyString());
```

Junit runs without any error but it supposed to fail since I have passed `Member_Servicing_Email_Update` in `when` and in `verify` its `Member_Servicing_Email_Update123`

Comment: Can you show `invokeAuditService` method signature? is it void/static?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585323/how-do-i-mock-a-static-method-that-returns-void-with-powermock

Comment: i don't get it. I am not able to connect the answer with my code.

Comment: mock statics the right way https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockstatic (or don use statics at all...)

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the following line, which is invalid syntax:
`PowerMockito.doNothing().when(WidgetHelper.class);`

When you create a mock all it method calls default to `doNothing`. So you do not need to declare it explictly.

However if you want to declare a behaviour you need to name the related method. Which is missing in the given line.